# Install SSL on Azure for ASP.NET Application

Tags: asp.net, azure, ssl

I have ASP.NET application with following detail

- It's upload on Microsoft Azure server
- Domain from ZNetLive Purchase
- SSL from GEOTRUST

I try to install SSL on server and set Nameserver and etc on ZNetLive using the following solution
https://knowledge.geotrust.com/support/knowledge-base/index?page=content&id=SO15284

Also try many other solution but install ssl success but when i open website i got error as below

[image]

Please help me to short out this problem

Comment: Just to confirm, have you hosted your Web app on Azure App Service or Virtual Machines?

Comment: Virtual machines